# How to hide ad banner offline or when no ad could be loaded - in React Native with Expo?

Tags: react-native, mobile, admob, expo, banner-ads

I implemented ads with the expo and admob in my react native app, but I would like to get rid of the blank/blocking space when no ads are being loaded. Haven't found any examples for that. (other than the banner, I have a header and scrollview on that page).
This is how the admob banner is implemented:

```js
// Display a banner
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" // Test ID, Replace    with your-admob-unit-id
  testDeviceID="EMULATOR" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to wrap the admob component in a view with styling to set height equal to zero. When you receive an ad. Then update the styling to show the banner in a view

```js
export class AdContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { height: 0 };
  }

  bannerError(e) {
    console.log('banner error: ');
    console.log(e);
  }
  adReceived() {
    console.log('banner ad received: ');
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      hasAd: true
    });
  }
  adClicked() {
    console.log('banner ad clicked: ');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={!this.state.hasAd ? { height: 0 } : {}}>
        <View>
          <AdMobBanner
            bannerSize="smartBannerPortrait" // "largeBanner" "fullBanner"
            adUnitID={BANNER_ID}
            testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
            onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError}
            onAdViewDidReceiveAd={this.adReceived.bind(this)}
            onAdViewWillPresentScreen={this.adClicked.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From reading their docs, you have 2 methods at your disposal:

```
onAdLoaded
```

> Accepts a function. Called when an ad is received.

```
onAdFailedToLoad
```

> Accepts a function. Called when an ad request failed.

If you are offline, you can check the network status like so:

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo

```js
NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then((connectionInfo) => {
  console.log('Initial, type: ' + connectionInfo.type + ', effectiveType: ' + connectionInfo.effectiveType);
});
function handleFirstConnectivityChange(connectionInfo) {
  console.log('First change, type: ' + connectionInfo.type + ', effectiveType: ' + connectionInfo.effectiveType);
  NetInfo.removeEventListener(
    'connectionChange',
    handleFirstConnectivityChange
  );
}
NetInfo.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  handleFirstConnectivityChange
);
```

I would check if the user is offline, or has a bad connection - and if online - render the Ad, and use the `onAdFailedToLoad` method to handle ad errors.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out these methods. Still not sure how I would hide the banner. Maybe I will check for connectivity and show the banner only if that is successful.

Comment: Perhaps a ternary statement? Let me know if you get stuck. Please accept and up vote if you found useful :)

Comment: but what exactly code you write in onAdFailedToLoad() to hide it?

Comment: Just use a true/false state variable.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several approaches... The problem with onAdFailedToLoad was that it doesn't seem to work when offline. The problem with listening to NetInfo was that a simple implementation only told the network status after a change.

I ended up using a library to discover whether the app was online:

https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline (implementation with redux)

and this approach to hide my admob banner (nested inside MyView):

https://medium.com/scripbox-engineering/how-to-hide-a-view-component-in-react-native-8a4994382c0.

Comment: but what exactly code you write in onAdFailedToLoad() to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hook solution.

Essentially you want to check if the ad has loaded, if not set the banner height to 0 so that it doesn't leave open empty space.

```
function MyAdContainer() {
  const [adLoaded, setAdLoaded] = useState(false) // initialize unloaded

  function handleAdLoaded() {
    setAdLoaded(true);
  }

  const containerStyles = adLoaded ? styles.bannerContainer : { height: 0 }; 

  return (
    <View style={containerStyles}>
      <BannerAd
        onAdLoaded={handleAdLoaded}
        {...OTHER_PROPS}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

In this case it doesn't matter if the ad failed or the user is offline because it initializes as `false`. So only in the case that an ad is successfully loaded do we give that component a height.